# Quiero revisar el registro de errores de PHP, ¿dónde lo encuentro?

Tags: php

> **NOTA**: Esta pregunta es planteada con la idea de que haya **una única respuesta que sea marcada como Wiki de comunidad**, para
>   impulsar el uso del log de errores, que nos ahorrará quizá horas
>   ayudando a encontrar de forma concreta la causa de casi todos los errores de programación.

Yo uso PHP en línea, ligado a un dominio alojado en hosting compartido.

En mi caso, el registro de errores es un archivo llamado `error_log`, que se crea en cada carpeta donde existen archivos php y alguno de esos archivos genera un error.

**Cuando algo falla, lo primero es revisar el `errorlog` en la carpeta donde corre el script PHP que está fallando**

Por mi experiencia aquí respondiendo preguntas, me doy cuenta de que un gran número de usuarios **no revisan el log de errores antes de preguntar**. Algunos dicen que **llevan días o horas** rompiéndose el coco sin encontrar el error, y cuando leo eso siempre pienso: ¡Ay, si supiera que existe un log de errores!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<sub>Vista parcial del log de errores, indicando la ruta del archivo que falla,  la línea y la causa del error.</sub>

La idea de esta pregunta es generar una respuesta que podría ser Wiki de comunidad, en la que se vayan indicando (según los frameworks, o según los hostings en que tengamos experiencia), la forma de acceder al log de errores.

También se pretende sensibilizar a los programadores que empiezan, o a los que ya empezaron hace un tiempo, a usar una herramienta tan útil de depuración que, a mi juicio no es usada en muchos casos por desconocimiento de la misma.

Entonces:

**¿Cómo encontrar el log de errores para depurar nuestros programas según la plataforma o framework PHP que estemos usando?**

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que iniciaras la primera respuesta con el framework que usas y dónde se encuentra el log en tu caso. Así el resto de personas que entren a la pregunta podrán completarla con sus frameworks correspondientes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En PHP el [registro (log) de errores](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php) sirve para:

> Enviar un mensaje de error a las rutinas de manejo de errores
> definidas

Este archivo contiene por tanto información valiosa sobre los errores que podrían estar ocurriendo en nuestro programa.

Sería la primera fuente a consultar para determinar dónde ocurre el error **exactamente**, ya que dicho registro da información sobre la ruta del script fallido, la causa del fallo y el número de línea donde se encuentra el error.

Una de las mayores dificultades de un registro de errores, sobre todo al principio, es que suele arrojar muchísima información (esto se agradecerá posteriormente), en inglés, y eso echa para atrás a cualquiera, sobre todo si no dominas la lengua de Shakespeare, y lo digo por experiencia propia, porque los registros de error me daban alergia al principio. Pero con un poco de paciencia, si le metes mano y aprendes a interpretarlos, te vas a ahorrar muchas, pero muchas horas en la depuración / corrección de errores.

Otra dificultad añadida, en entornos de servidor, es que puede no ser fácil identificar dónde se encuentra el archivo que registra los errores, porque su ubicación puede variar según la configuración del servidor, el sistema operativo, etc. O también dicho registro puede estar deshabilitado, en cuyo caso los errores no se registran.

Pero hay formas de saber todo esto y es lo que voy a explicar a continuación.

Consideremos esta respuesta usando dos vías para encontrar tan importante fuente de información.

### La vía rápida

Nos permitirá al menos saber cómo se llama nuestro archivo. Sabiendo su nombre, podremos buscar su ubicación más fácilmente.

Para ello podemos ejecutar en una página cualquiera:

```
phpinfo();
```

Esta llamada mostrará toda la configuración de nuestro PHP. Suele ser mucha información, por lo que puedes hacer una búsqueda con la palabra `error` por ejemplo. De paso compruebas si el registro (log) de errores está o no activado.

Aquí está casi todo lo que nos interesa saber:

- que el archivo en este caso se llama **`error_log`** (primer recuadro en amarillo)
- que la escritura de errores está activada: **`log_errors`: On** (segundo recuadro en amarillo, casi al final). No confundir con lo que dice arriba: `display_errors`, que está en `Off`. Eso es para que no se muestren los errores en la pantalla del cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora sólo nos queda buscar la ubicación de nuestro archivo de errores. La cual puede variar según el contexto. Por ejemplo en  mi caso: hosting compartido Bluehost para una página web, se crea un archivo en cada carpeta. Cuando un archivo de esa carpeta falla, se escribe en el log de errores.

Otra cosa a tomar en cuenta es que **los últimos errores se escriben siempre al final del archivo**, no al principio del mismo. Si hay muchísimos errores el archivo puede crecer, incluso muchos megabytes. Para evitar eso, lo primero es tener un código optimizado claro está, evitando que ocurran mensajes del tipo *Undefined index...*  No seas vago y verifica las variables antes de intentar usarlas. Y, este archivo se puede ir limpiando cada `N` meses por ejemplo. Algunos hosting lo hacen automáticamente, o lo puedes hacer tú manualmente, por ejemplo, borrando el archivo (en ese caso se creará uno nuevo cuando hayan de nuevo errores) o seleccionando todo su contenido y borrándolo.

> **IMPORTANTE:** No olvides borrar la llamada a `phpinfo()` una vez obtenida la información requerida, podrías estar dejando expuesta
> información sensible sobre tu sitio, sobre todo si es una página web.

---

### La vía directa (según tu plataforma)

Aquí una tabla para completar con la ubicación del log de errores según los frameworks o hostings más usados.

La respuesta es Wiki de comunidad, si tienes experiencia con algún entorno / framework, tómate 3 minutos para editarla, poniendo en la última fila la forma en que se accede al log de errores.

Cuida de no estropear la tabla. Al escribir alguna rayita vertical se moverá, re-colócala de forma que quede debajo de las otras.

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╗
║   Framework             ║   Nombre       ║      Ruta del archivo               ║  
║   o Hosting             ║ de archivo     ║      O Recurso Web (Pluggin)        ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Bluehost                ║ error_log      ║ Carpeta de cada script (*)          ║ 
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║ Symfony                 ║ monolog-bundle ║ No definida; Recurso 1              ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║ phpCake                 ║ error.log      ║ $app/tmp/logs/                      ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║ PHP Nativo              ║ error-log      ║ funcion Nativa de PHP; Recurso 2    ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║ PHP Nativo              ║ set-error-hand ║ funcion Nativa de PHP; Recurso 3    ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
║-------------------------║----------------║-------------------------------------║ 
║                         ║                ║                                     ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- <sub>(*) Es importante señalar que el error se escribirá en la carpeta del script que llama. Si por ejemplo, tengo un script llamado `llamador.php` que funciona bien, pero llama otro archivo con error que se llama `llamado.php` que está en otra carpeta. El error se escribirá en la carpeta donde se encuentra `llamador.php`,  aunque sea `llamado.php` el que falle. Por supuesto, el log nos dirá que error está en `llamado.php`.</sub>
- <sub>Recurso 1: [Link](https://www.christophh.net/2013/10/17/log-to-error-log-in-symfony2/)</sub>
- Recurso 2: [Link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-log.php)
- Recurso 3: [Link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php)

### Log de errores en desarrollo

Si estamos **desarrollando en Windows con Xampp** (versión 3.x) el log de errores de PHP está accesible siguiendo los siguientes pasos:

> 1. Abrir el panel de control de XAMPP.
> 2. Para el servicio Apache clicar el botón "Logs".
> 3. Seleccionar "PHP (php_error_log)"

Es una opción poco utilizada ya que si tenemos *display_errors* en *ON*, "normalmente" el propio intérprete nos mostrará los errores, pero puede ser necesaria cuando trabajamos con código de terceros en el que se han *silenciado los errores* dentro del propio código.

### Log de errores propios de frameworks

Los frameworks y algunas otras herramientas pueden implementar su propio sistema de logs que registran errores y ,en ocasiones, otro tipo de mensajes.

Los **logs de Laravel 5** podemos encontrarlos en el directorio "storage/logs/".

Comment: En la mayoría de los casos el hacer el output de errores o cualquier tipo de log requerirá de algún complemente de tercero o de programación adicional es importante si no es nativo que dejen el recurso Documentado tambien.

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder al **log de errores de PHP si estamos desarrollando con XAMPP en Windows** (versión 3.x):

> 1. Abrir el panel de control de XAMPP.
> 2. Para el servicio *Apache* clicar el botón "Logs".
> 3. Seleccionar "PHP (php_error_log)"

En cuanto a los *frameworks* y algunas otras herramientas cada uno implementa su propio sistema de logs, en **Laravel 5** podemos encontrarlos en el directorio "storage/logs/".

Comment: Gracias. Eras libre de [editar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/116433/edit) y añadir esta valiosa información, para ello precisamente está marcada como Wiki de comunidad. Si tienes miedo de que la tabla quede trastocada no hay problema, avisas y la arreglamos :)

Answer (score 0):

Los Logs puedes conseguirlos en la ruta de PHP si lo marcaste, pero que pasa si no lo marcastes?? pues tambien existe .

Asumiendo que tienes conocimientos basicos de Apache2 y realizaste la instalacion en un servidor gnu/linux

Debes buscar en la carpeta por defecto `/var/log/apache2/` alli encontraras todos los logs generados por dia de `apache2/PHP`

Pero, Que pasa si tienes varios virtualhost y no sabes cual pagina web PHP dio error . pues simple miremos un virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_api_1.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_api_1.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Como podras observar existe una variable `ErrorLog` que te dice donde esta ubicado (`${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` es la ubicacion por defecto), Tambien este almacena los errores de PHP asi que no te es necesario habilitar el error de PHP salvo quieras almacenarlo en otra ruta

**ADICIONAL:**

> Puedes decirle a tu Virtualhost que error almacenar para eso existen
>   la Palabra reservada LogInfo puedes tambien te invito a [leer mas
>   sobre manejo de errores de
>   Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)