# Mi Update no funciona

Tags: php, html, sql, formularios

Estoy intentando esto:

```
 <?php

    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $emai   = $_POST['emai'];
    $pass   = $_POST['pass'];
    $tel    = $_POST['tel'];
    $dir    = $_POST['dir'];
    $id     = $_SESSION['usuario']['ID'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Oops: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

        $cambio = "UPDATE Usuarios SET name='$nombre', email='$emai', password='$pass', phone='$tel', address='$dir' WHERE ID='$id'";        

        if (($result=$conn->query($cambio)) === true) {
            echo $_SESSION['usuario']['name'];
        } else {
            echo "Error: ";
        }

    } else {

        echo"oops";

    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

Con este formulario:

```
<form action="vcambio.php" method="post">
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>cambiar nombre</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="email" name="emai" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Cambiar Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Cambiar Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="tel" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Cambiar Telefono</label>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="text" name="dir" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Cambiar direccion</label>
    </div>    
    <input type="submit" name="sumbitt" value="Guardar Cambios"</input>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitt'])) {
        require ("vcambio.php");
    }
?>
```

No encuentro el error cuando lo ejecuto. Imprime las variables de la sesión anterior. No me lanza error pero no actualiza las variables, cuando lo consulto en `phpmyadmin` sigue igual que antes.

Comment: Y cual es el error que te lanza?

Comment: no me lanza error pero no hace update a las variables cuando lo consulto en phpmyadmin sigue igual que antes

Comment: Puedes confirmarnos que el `if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))` si se esta ejecutando?

Comment: si todo funciona menos el update

Comment: Ya revisastes si no es error en tu base de datos, que tienes algun campo declarado de un tipo y tratas de ingresar datos que no acepta

Comment: Si los revise y estan correctos

Comment: @ger Has revisado también tu `require`, le faltan las `''`, es decir, tu código `require conexion.php;` cámbialo por `require 'conexion.php';`, a ver si así funciona, también cambia `WHERE email='$email'` por `WHERE email='$emai'` ya que `$email` no la encuentro.

Comment: decidi cambiar el where email por where id

Comment: @ger Aun así no estas añadiendo correctamente tu conexión, ya que te faltan las `''` como te he comentado antes, debería lanzarte algún error como `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'`. Tampoco habrá mucha diferencia entre un ID o email como identificador, ya que si tu *Base de Datos* esta correctamente estructurada, tu campo email, debería ser único (unique) y debería funcionar de igual forma.

Comment: aun con las comillas no funciona

Comment: El `UPDATE` puede fallar por infinitos motivos, entre ellos los que se han dicho en comentarios... y **un fallo muy silencioso es el de consultas que violan la integridad de la BD al producir registros duplicados**. Sea cual sea el error, lo primerísimo de todo sería **[revisar tu log de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967)**, el cual te dirá exactamente lo que está ocurriendo y dónde está ocurriendo. Si aprendes a usarlo, te ahorrarás horas y días que a veces solemos perder tratando de encontrar dónde está el error.

Comment: no aparece ningun error en el log

Comment: Sube la estructura de tu base de datos, y escribe lo siguiente en tu archivo: session_start(); echo $_SESSION['usuario']; die(); si te muestra el nombre del usuario significa que esta bien y puedo darte una respuesta, si no te muestra eso, ahi radica el error

Comment: cuando escribo si lo hace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propongo que pruebes esta solución. En ella:

1. Aplico el principio de consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código
2. Escribo un código *obligado a hablar*. En todo el recorrido va añadiendo un mensaje a la variable `$arrMensaje`, la cual se imprime al final para decirte lo que ocurrió en el código. Yo llamo a este principio *código controlado*. Considero que el programador no debe nunca escribir un código que falle sin que él sepa por qué falla. Aquí te dirá lo que sea.
3. Para que el código funcione, debes controlar algunas cosas, por ejemplo tu columna `ID` ¿se escribe todo con mayúscula?. Ten en cuenta que los nombres de tabla y columna son *case sensitive*. Bueno, si lo tienes mal escrito lo sabrás, el código te lo dirá.
4. También, al hacer el binding, es necesario que me confirmes si tu columna `ID` es del tipo VARCHAR en la base de datos o si es numérico...

Dicho eso, aquí vamos. Espero que puedas probarlo y comentes el resultado:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $emai   = $_POST['emai'];
    $pass   = $_POST['pass'];
    $tel    = $_POST['tel'];
    $dir    = $_POST['dir'];
    $id     = $_SESSION['usuario']['ID'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {

        $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Error: Fallo de conexión");

    }else{

        if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

            $strSQL = "UPDATE Usuarios SET name=?, email=?, password=?, phone=?, address=? WHERE ID=?";      
            $stmt=$conn->prepare($strSQL);


            if ($stmt){

                $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $nombre,$emai,$pass,$tel,$dir,$id);

                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $intFilas=$stmt->affected_rows;  
                    $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Actualizado. Filas afectadas: ".$intFilas.PHP_EOL."Sesión: ".$_SESSION['usuario']['name']);

                }else{

                    $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"No se cumplieron los criterios o clave duplicada " . $stmt->error);
                }

            }else{

                $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"Error: La consulta falló No Error: ".$stmt->errno . "Causa: " . $stmt->error);            
                $stmt->close();
            }


        } else {

            $arrMensaje=array("mensaje"=>"No hay sesión de usuario");

        }

        $conn->close();

    }

    echo $arrMensaje["mensaje"];
?>
```

Comment: ID es en mayusculas y de tipo int autoincrement

Comment: Entonces @ger, el código conlleva una pequeña variación aquí: `$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $nombre,$emai,$pass,$tel,$dir,$id);`  ya lo he editado. La última `i`, aquí: `sssssi` indica que el último parámetro es un número. Debes confirmarme que todos los demás valores son del tipo `VARCHAR`, porque cualquiera de ellos que sea entero, debe tener también `i`  en esa cadena de `sss...` que hay en el `bind_param`.

Comment: son de tipo text

Comment: Entonces no hay problema, con el `bind_param` como está, debería funcionar. Prueba y comenta el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

tendrías que pasar un ID de usuario por session ... para que por allí se rija el update de tu WHERE (donde está tu problemilla)

En lo que pasaste de códigos, no hay una variable "$email", pero si "$emai"

```
WHERE email='$email'
```

(---Planteamiento---)
Si yo tengo todos mis datos y como email "ads@asd.com" quiero cambiar a "hola@hola.com" en tu WHERE va a buscar el correo hola@hola.com para cambiarlo por hola@hola.com y no buscará a ads@asd.com (según la query que estas usando, a menos que su mail actual lo guardes como session o le pases por input hydden (el cual radica después en implementar en unas lineas mas para controlar que no lo manipulen antes de enviarlo al php+sql))

Comment: no funcionó por ID sigue igual

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require conexion.php;

    extract($_POST); // importa a la lista de variables lo que llega por $_POST

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Oops: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

        $cambio = "UPDATE Usuarios SET name='$nombre', email='$emai', password='$pass', phone='$tel', address='$dir' WHERE ID='$id'";        

        if (($conn->query($cambio))) 
        {
            echo $_SESSION['usuario']['name'];
        } else {
            echo "Error: ";
        }

    } else {

        echo"oops";

    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```

De todas formas, como no puedo ver el archivo conexion.php, es imposible averiguar si la conexión está bien hecha...

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Saludos

Comment: gracias pedro pero no se soluciona el problema

Answer (score 1):

Otro error aparte las que han sido modificados por los comentarios es en el siguiente paso:

```
if (($result=$conn->query($cambio)) === true) {
```

Veo demasiados llaves de apertura y cierre `()`, de hecho hice una prueba, y me mando un error.

> **error:** `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in...`, gusto en dicha línea.

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
$result = $conn->query("UPDATE Usuarios SET name='$nombre', email='$emai', password='$pass', phone='$tel', address='$dir' WHERE ID=$id"); 

if (true===$result) { }
```

o

```
if ($conn->query($cambio) === true)
```

### Un posible ejemplo:

**conexion.php**

```
$conn = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "BaseDatos");

/* verificar conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallo: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    //echo 'Existe conexión.';
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    session_start();        
    //Reset
    $nombre = $emai = $pass = $tel = $dir = $id = NULL;

    //Si esta definido el formulario
    if (isset($_POST['sumbitt'])) {     
        //Obtener datos del formulario
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $emai   = $_POST['emai'];
        $pass   = $_POST['pass'];
        $tel    = $_POST['tel'];
        $dir    = $_POST['dir'];
        $id     = $_SESSION['usuario']['ID'];

        //Si esta definido la sesion.
        if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
            //Verdadero datos a trabajar.
            if ($nombre && $emai && $pass && $tel && $dir && $id) {
                //Conexion (Importante llamar a la conexión dodne vas a trabajar con el).
                require 'conexion.php';
                //Sentencia
                $result = $conn->query("UPDATE Usuarios SET name='$nombre', email='$emai', password='$pass', phone='$tel', address='$dir' WHERE ID=$id");        
                //Comprabación si se ejecuto la sentencia.
                if (true===$result) {
                    echo $_SESSION['usuario']['name'];
                } else {
                    exit('Fallo el update: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
                }                   
            }
        } else {
            echo"oops hubo un error en tu sesión.";
        }   
    }

?>
```

> **Nota:** Te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: no imprime nada

Comment: @ger Tampoco te actualizo? Probé en localhost la sentencia actualizando solo un dato y si funciono perfecto, eso sí con otra Base de Datos.

Comment: no no me actualizó aparece en blanco

Comment: las variables deben ser iguales a las que ingresé al registrar los datos o deben ser diferentes?

Comment: @ger no te entendí con tu último comentario? Sobre qué variables deben ser iguales?

Comment: cuando registro usuarios digo `$name=$_POST['name']` `<input name="name">` y cuando actualizo usuarios digo `$nombre=$_POST['nombre']` `<input name="nombre">`

Comment: @ger si eso está correcto, se usa el identificador `name` para crear tus variables en `PHP`. Es un poco raro, ya que lo probé en `localhost`, aún así déjame luego más tarde crear una BD igual, que estoy ahora mismo con el móvil, ya que el resto que e añadido aparte no lo probé.