# Problemas al conectarme desde apache (ubuntu) a sql server mediante PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, sql-server-2008

voy a intentar explicarme:
Quiero conectarme desde un servidor que tengo xubuntu a sql server 2008 mediante una consulta php. 
Ya tengo instalados los driver necesarios y las extensiones en el servidor.
La consulta de ejemplo que me da microsoft si consigo conectarme ya que me devuelve los datos del servidor, el problema esta que con la consulta que tenia y funciona en window no consigo conectarme.

Codigo con el cual me conecta perfectamente:

```
<?php
$serverName = "172.26.7.192";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "A3LABORAL",
    "Uid" => "consulta",
    "PWD" => "Monte00!"
);

//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors()));
}

//Select Query
$tsql= "select * from [master].[dbo].[ZMontesano_Vista_Agenda]";

//Executes the query
$getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

//Error handling
if ($getResults == FALSE)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
?>



<?php
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo ($row['SQL_VERSION']);
    echo ("<br/>");
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);


function FormatErrors( $errors )
{
    /* Display errors. */
    echo "Error information: <br/>";
    foreach ( $errors as $error )
    {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error['SQLSTATE']."<br/>";
        echo "Code: ".$error['code']."<br/>";
        echo "Message: ".$error['message']."<br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

Problema al usar PDO y Funcionando desde local en window:

```
<?php
    echo "nada";
    $pdo=new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=172.26.7.192;Database=A3LABORAL", "consulta", "Monte00!");
    $statement=$pdo->prepare("select * from [master].[dbo].[ZMontesano_Vista_Agenda]");
    $statement->execute();
    if (!$statement){
        echo 'Error al ejecutar la consulta';
    echo "no entro";
    }else{
        $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo  json_encode($results);
    echo "entro";

    }
    ?>
```

Dejo una imagen de muestra: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias

Comment: Imprime el mensaje de error y dinos cuál es: `if (!$statement){
        echo 'Error al ejecutar la consulta'; print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); //... resto del código`

Comment: lo siento, pero ni siquiera llega ejecutarse esa parte del codigo ya que tengo varios echo, y no imprime ninguno

Comment: Entonces puede que no esté conectando. Pon la conexión en un bloque `try`, [como indica la doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017), entonces te dirá lo que está ocurriendo realmente
: `try  
{  
$pdo = new PDO( **credenciales aquí**);  
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
}  
catch(Exception $e)  
{   
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}`  o bien [revisa el `error_log`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967).

Comment: ejecuta tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log para ver los registros del servidor web y tener una idea de que esta pasando

Comment: @A.Cedano  me devuelve could not find driver1 (ni idea de que significa)

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez 
[Thu Apr 26 14:19:34.941221 2018] [php7:error] [pid 28172] [client ::1:34880] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /var/www/html/php/cartas.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/php/cartas.php(4): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=1...', 'consulta', 'Monte00!')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/php/cartas.php on line 4

Comment: Es muy probable que no le estés pasando bien la cadena de conexión, los parámetros dentro de `new (...)`. [Revisa los ejemplos del Manual, en la parte que dice: **Ejemplos**](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php), escogiendo la forma que se adapte a tu caso.

Comment: si presisamente es por los driver de conexcion abajo te dejo una repsuesta

Comment: En el enlace de mi anterior comentario del Manual de PHP, justo al final, en el apartado **User Contributed Notes** hay un comentario muy interesante que explica la diferencia en que hay que usar PDO en SQL Server según el driver que tengas. Sería conveniente que la leas. Siempre me ha parecido algo problemático conectarse a PDO cuando se trata de SQL Server, esa nota parece explicar con claridad el motivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas Gracias por la ayuda le echare un vistaso.

Comment: Si te conecta usando la primera forma que indicas, entonces podrías usar ese objeto `$conn` para ejecutar la segunda consulta, esa que dices que no te funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar tu servidor apache de linux a un servidor de base de datos en windows hay varias formas una de ellas es usar FreTDS:

```
#sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin libodbc1 
odbcinst1debian2 tdsodbc php5-odbc
#sudo apt-get install -y freetds-bin freetds-common freetds-dev libct4 
libsybdb5
```

Luego debes configugarlo para que se conecte a tu host de Base de Datos, te dejo el link de laninformacion para que la revises. es un poco complicado pero si es posible:

https://gist.github.com/ghalusa/97bf0b45a27d6b025d670752a7c62ec6

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, es buena, pero ya me conecta, el problema esta en que no consigo ejecutar la segunda consulta que muestro, aunque en la primera si me devuelve bien los valores