# Cómo solucionar error 500 al generar PDF con php

Tags: php, web, cpanel

tengo una página web que me genera unos reportes de pedidos con un pdf, el caso es que en local me funciona de maravilla, pero a la hora de alojarla en el servidor cuándo quiero consultar estos reporte, me aparece Error 500, lo que me parece raro del asunto es que aparece aparentemente aleatorio, es decir, le doy a consultar un reporte y a veces me aparece Error 500 y otra veces me genera el reporte bien, otra de las cosas extrañas es que cuando estoy en la página de Error 500 si actualizo, me genera el reporte, ya revisé los permisos, el .htaccess y todo está correcto, alguna idea de que puede suceder?

Comment: ¿Cuánto tarda en generarse el reporte? El error puede deberse al tiempo de ejecución, permisos, memoria, etc. Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar el código que estás usando.

Comment: Hola, el reporte lo genera instantáneo, no demora mas de un segundo. y cómo te digo, es muy extraño, porque exactamente el mismo reporte en ocasiones lo genera y en ocasiones no, y si le doy actualizar a la pagina cuando no lo genera, en ese instante sí lo genera. Lo que he pensado es que puede que el servidor esté un poco inestable y por eso en ocasiones funcione y en ocasiones no, ¿qué opinas?    PD: no puedo ponerte el código porque para la empresa que laboro tienen políticas muy estrictas de privacidad.

Comment: el error.log que dice?

Comment: @aloMalbarez está vacío.

Comment: fijate como usar el phpinfo para encontrar el error log que usa php ( y si está activo ) https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116433/81450 lo mas seguro es que sea que se queda sin memoria el php

Comment: @aloMalbarez revisaré eso, muchas gracias.