# Recursos de sitio web externo no funcionan

Tags: php

Estimados tengo la siguiente función en PHP la cual funciona a la perfección en localhost, pero a la hora se ejecutarla en mi sitio web es como si no accediera a los recursos de la pagina externa

el sitio en el que trabajo es **portal.ecuservicechile.cl** , la función es la siguiente, debo poner alguna regla en **.htaccess** o algo por el estilo ? , estaría agradecido de su ayuda.

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../vendor/autoload.php'; 
use Transbank\Webpay\Configuration;
use Transbank\Webpay\Webpay;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebPayNormal;
class WebpayPlusNormalController {
    
    public function getTransaction() {
        $urlRepository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-webpay-credenciales/master/";
        $dirFiles = "integracion/Webpay%20Plus%20-%20CLP/597020000540";

        $contentPublicCert = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".crt");
        $contentPrivateKey = file_get_contents($urlRepository . $dirFiles . ".key");

        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $configuration->setCommerceCode(597020000540);
        $configuration->setEnvironment("INTEGRACION");
        $configuration->setPrivateKey($contentPrivateKey);
        $configuration->setPublicCert($contentPublicCert);
        $webpay = new Webpay($configuration);
        return $webpay->getNormalTransaction();
    }
}

?>
```

Si en localhost hago lo siguiente

```
return openssl_x509_parse($contentPublicCert);
```

Obtengo lo que se detalla a continuación, pero en el servidor donde se encuentra alojada mi web, si ejecuto las mismas líneas de código, no me devuelve nada. Tengo exactamente los mismos archivos que en localhost, no hay nada mas, ni nada menos.

```
{
    "name": "/C=cl/ST=stgo/L=stgo/O=tbk/OU=ccrr/CN=597020000540/emailAddress=ccrr@gmail.com",
    "subject": {
        "C": "cl",
        "ST": "stgo",
        "L": "stgo",
        "O": "tbk",
        "OU": "ccrr",
        "CN": "597020000540",
        "emailAddress": "ccrr@gmail.com"
    },
    "hash": "2d17efa6",
    "issuer": {
        "C": "cl",
        "ST": "stgo",
        "L": "stgo",
        "O": "tbk",
        "OU": "ccrr",
        "CN": "597020000540",
        "emailAddress": "ccrr@gmail.com"
    },
    "version": 0,
    "serialNumber": "16407850704409370121",
    "serialNumberHex": "E3B465487BF69E09",
    "validFrom": "180608134606Z",
    "validTo": "220607134606Z",
    "validFrom_time_t": 1528465566,
    "validTo_time_t": 1654609566,
    "signatureTypeSN": "RSA-SHA256",
    "signatureTypeLN": "sha256WithRSAEncryption",
    "signatureTypeNID": 668,
    "purposes": {
        "1": [
            true,
            true,
            "sslclient"
        ],
        "2": [
            true,
            true,
            "sslserver"
        ],
        "3": [
            true,
            true,
            "nssslserver"
        ],
        "4": [
            true,
            true,
            "smimesign"
        ],
        "5": [
            true,
            true,
            "smimeencrypt"
        ],
        "6": [
            true,
            true,
            "crlsign"
        ],
        "7": [
            true,
            true,
            "any"
        ],
        "8": [
            true,
            true,
            "ocsphelper"
        ],
        "9": [
            false,
            true,
            "timestampsign"
        ]
    },
    "extensions": []
}
```

Comment: lo que muestras en el codigo es una clase que tiene un metodo. Pero no vemos donde instancias la clase y donde llamas al metodo... Es en otra parte del codigo? asi como tal, no se ve ejecucion posible...

Comment: Este código es parte de una librería. ¿Tienes instalada dicha librería en remoto? En este tipo de casos es fundamental revisar el log de errores para determinar con exactitud el problema. En tu pregunta no dices nada al respecto. Así te puedes pasar horas pensando por qué tu código no funciona, cuando tienes una herramienta que te ahorrará muchas horas cuando aprendas a usarla. Aprender a revisar el log de errores es algo que lo agradecerás toda la vida, en cualquier lenguaje. [Revisa aquí para el caso de PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967).

Comment: Uso una clase llamada Transbank la cual si esta instalada en mi servidor y la llamado mediante vendor/autoload, las clases Transbank si funcionan, lo que no funciona es la variable que hace referencia a la página externa, pero en el servidor local si funciona, el código es tal cual en local

Comment: Hola una pregunta, la variable $contentPublicCert y $contentPrivateKey que contienen cuando lo ejecutas en servidor? ¿Y cuál es el error que muestra?

Comment: Pregunta editada, ahí detalle los resultados que obtengoen localhost