# ¿Cómo conectarme a una BD de firebird/interbase desde PHP y hacer altas masivos?

Tags: php, firebase, pdo, firebird2.5

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$str_conn="firebird:host=localhost;dbname=C://xampp//htdocs//fdb//$dbname.FDB;charset=UTF8";
            //$conn = new PDO($str_conn, $firebird_user, $firebird_pass); //Establezco la conexión con la base de datos
            try{
                $conn = new PDO($str_conn, $firebird_user, $firebird_pass);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e){
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
                return false; //Migración manual
            }
            if (!$conn){
                if($debug) echo 'Error al intentar acceder a la base de datos '.$path_dst."\n";
                return false; //Se procederá con la migración manual
            }else{
                if($debug) echo 'Conexión con la base de datos '.$path_dst. ' establecida correctamente'."\n";
                foreach($sqls as $sql){ //Recorro todas las sentencias SQL
                    $result = $conn->exec($sql); //Hago un query por cada sentencia SQL.
                    if (!$result){ //Falla
                        $num_errors++;
                        $res = false;
                    }
                    else $num_ok++; //No falla
                }
                if($debug){
                        $msg = ($res)? 'sin errores':'con errores';
                        echo 'La migración de '.$csvFullPath.' a '. $path_dst. ' finalizó '. $msg.'.'."\n";
                        echo 'Cantidad de sentencias ejecutadas correctamente: '.$num_ok. '.'."\n";
                        echo 'Cantidad de sentencias ejecutadas con errores: '.$num_errors. '.'. "\n";
                } 
            }
        }else {
            if($debug) echo 'Se produjo un error al copiar el fichero '.$dbname. ' a '. $path_dst."\n";
            $res = false;
            return $res; //Se procederá con la migración manual
        }
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto de forma masiva? es decir, con una sóla ejecutar que se den de alta los N inserts y el delete?

Comment: El mensaje dice: `sentencias ejecutadas correctamente: 199` , significa que las sentencias se estarían ejecutando. ¿No estarás revisando en la BD equivocada y por eso no ves los datos? ¿Qué tipo de consultas estás ejecutando? Aunque no veo de dónde sale `$debug` ni por qué evalúas tanto a esa variable ¿?

Comment: $debug es una variable booleana. Si el valor es "true" muestra mensajes de debug y en caso contrario no lo hace. Los tipos de SQL que estoy intentando ejecutar son INSERTS. Lo de la DB no creo, porque lo que hace es coger todas las bases de datos que estén en el directorio /FBD (sólo hay una) y las copia a FDB_GENERATED y hace los inserts en esta última.

Comment: Vale, tienes razón. Por despistado estaba generando todo en la que se encuentra en /FDB, ahora cambié eso pero me sale lo siguiente: La migración de C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\midb\datos.csv a C:\xampp\htdocs\fdb_generated\midb.FDB finalizó con errores. Cantidad de sentencias ejecutadas correctamente: 198. Cantidad de sentencias ejecutadas con errores: 1. Si te preguntas cuál falló, pues es la siguiente "DELETE FROM MITABLA;" ¿Los delete debo ejecutarlos de otra forma?

Comment: Ya, pero no veo de dónde sale esa variable `$debug`. En cuanto a la consulta, la forma segura de saber si se han insertado filas es verificando las filas afectadas. Por tanto, haz el incremento de `$num_ok` basándote en `rowCount()` de este modo: **`$num_ok += $result->rowCount();`**  Si haciendo eso te dice que hay 199 inserciones o las que sea, las hay, otra cosa es que se estén insertando en una determinada base de datos en la cual no estés revisando.

Comment: `DELETE FROM miTabla` te estaría borrando todos los registros de esa tabla. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: Sí, quiero que el DELETE sea la primera sentencia SQL que se ejecute, luego irían los N INSERTS. En este caso serían 1 delete + 198 inserts

Comment: En ese caso, organiza tu archivo CSV de modo que la primera fila sea el `DELETE`. Como ya dije, esa setencia limpiará la tabla, borrando todos sus registros. Y, si en esa tabla hay una columna auto-increment la misma no volverá a contar a partir de 1.

Comment: Sí, es la sentencia que se genera primero pero falla al ser ejecutada. ¿Hay forma de capturar la razón del error?.

Comment: En esta parte: `if (!$result){` puedes poner **temporalmente** esto: `var_dump($conn->errorInfo());`  y verás el motivo del error. He puesto temporalmente, porque no conviene mostrar al usuario los mensajes de error, úsalo sólo en fase de depuración. Aunque un método mejor para depurar es [revisar los log de errores de PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967).

Comment: Vale! haré eso que me has dicho. Sabes que la línea ->rowCount me ha fallado. "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on int in". La modificación ha quedado de esta forma:                     if (!$result){ //Falla
      $num_errors++;
      $res = false;
                        echo "Falló la SQL: ".$sql."<br>";
                    }
     else $num_ok += $result->rowCount();

Comment: Ya, eso es porque estás usando `exec` , el cual te devolvería las filas afectadas, entonces puedes cambiarlo por esto: `$num_ok += $result;`  pues ahí `$result` sería el número de filas afectadas. Aunque para este contexto es mucho mejor usar consultas preparadas, porque son más rápidas (se trata de varias ejecuciones). Cuando preparas una consulta el manejador traza el plan para la misma y las ejecuciones posteriores (dentro del mismo bucle) son más rápidas.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a INSERTS masivos? no sé cómo hacerlos aquí, pero tengo un array con todas las SQL. Como habrás visto en mi código, hago un foreach de las sqls y por cada una hago un exec.

Comment: con respecto a la línea de código que me has dado, es decir, var_dump($conn->errorInfo()), la misma retorna lo siguiente: "array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }". El delete sigue fallando y no sé la razón porque la sintaxis está bien

Comment: Claro, es lo que ocurre ahí, por cada iteracción del `foreach` ocurre una consulta. Si quieres optimizar, lo propio sería: 1. Preparar la consulta una sola vez fuera del bucle; 2. Ejecutar cada consulta dentro del bucle. Pero eso significa organizar tu CSV, por ejemplo, diferenciando la consulta DELETE de las consultas INSERT. O, yendo más lejos, creando una sola consulta que inserte todos los valores en una sola ejecución, o bien usando transacciones o bien separando los valores en sí mismos para pasarlos con `bindParam` para evitar inyección SQL. Las posibilidades son varias.

Comment: Me gustaría optimizarlo generando todos los INSERTS en una sóla ejecución ¿podrías dar respuesta a esta preguntada con un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo? Por otro lado ¿alguna idea de por qué falla el DELETE? (no hay error de sintaxis y la conexión con la DB está correctamente establecida) ¿puede ser porque la base de datos en /fdb está vacía? entonces se hace una copia en /fdb_generated, se ejecuta el delete (no hay nada y falla) y luego los inserts (funcionan). No se me ocurre otra cosa

Comment: Con respecto al `DELETE`, [lee la documentacion sobre `exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.exec.php), en casos de `INSERT`, `DELETE` o `UPDATE` ese método te devuelve las filas afectadas. Por tanto, el código está entrando en esa parte simplemente **porque hay `0` filas borradas**. El `var_dump` que te sugerí antes confirma que no hay errores, simplemente, no hay filas borradas. Debes dar coherencia a tu código y a tu CSV, nunca es bueno mezclar tipos de consultas, de hecho esta situación lo demuestra, porque estarías usando un mismo código para controlar eliminaciones e inserciones.

Comment: Sí, acabo de comprobarlo. Moví la sentencia DELETE al final y se ejecutó correctamente, así que, realmente no está fallando. Muchas gracias por todo. Modificaré un poco la pregunta para que me puedas dar una respuesta para hacer todo masivamente. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: En cuanto a una sola inserción, no depende de este contexto, sino del contexto donde creas tu CSV. Es allí donde debes crear una consulta como esta: `INSERT INTO laTabla (col1, col2, colN)  VALUES ('a1', 'a2', 'aN'), ('b1', 'b2', 'bN'), ('c1', 'c2', 'cN');` aquí `a, b, c` serían tres filas. Esa es una sola consulta, con varias inserciones y deberías construirlo así en el CSV. Aún quedan aspectos pendientes, como la **seguridad**. Ten en cuenta que cualquier usuario que tenga acceso a escribir en ese CSV te puede colar una *inyección SQL*,  es un tema amplio pero que no debe ignorarse.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo. Ahora viene la pregunta del millón ¿Sabes (sí o no) si desde PHP se puede generar ficheros .FDB (crear la base de datos)? Esto sería lo ideal pero lo veo imposible. ¿Por qué sería lo ideal? porque se generarían bases de datos exactamente basadas en los ficheros CSV. Ahora mismo si alguien pone una base de cuyos que tenga, al menos, una tabla con una columna diferente, la migración finalizaría con errores.

Comment: No conozco Firebird, pero no creo que sea imposible generar (crear) una base de datos de forma programática y usando como fuente de datos un archivo `.csv` o cualquier otra fuente. Algunos SGBD ofrecen de hecho  la posibilidad de cargar datos directamente desde archivos, no sé si Firebird lo permita, y si no lo permite, puedes en todo caso leer el archivo para crear un INSERT que guardarías en la base de datos que estarás generando programáticamente. Sea como sea, conviene que investigues, intentes y si tienes algún problema que lo plantees en una nueva pregunta.