# Crear archivo json con Ajax y PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy intentando crear un archivo json a traves de una petición ajax y un fichero PHP, pero el problema es que aunque me devuelve la salida correctamente, no me crea el archivo. ¿Alguna ayuda de por que puede ser?

JS
let json = JSON.stringify(datosGaleria);

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'generarArchivo.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: json,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function(response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert('Archivo guardado con éxito');
            } else {
                alert('El archivo no ha podido ser guardado');
            }
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST)){
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $datos = json_decode($json);
    $json_string = json_encode($datos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    $fecha = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid') );
    $fechaString = $fecha->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $file = 'backup/'.$fechaString.' backup.json';
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
    echo 'Exito';
  }
  
 ?>
```

[image: Ruta]

Comment: $file = 'backup/'.$fechaString.' backup.json';
Las comillas simples están bien usadas?

Comment: [Revisa el log de errores en el servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) y dinos qué muestra. No sabemos si el servidor está recibiendo bien la petición desde el cliente, si `$json_string` es un JSON válido, si tienes permisos para guardar archivos en `backup`, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, al parecer la carpeta log no estaba creada. Me sale como error: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(backup/07-06-2021 19:16:07 backup.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in La cosa es que la carpeta backup esta en el mismo sitio que el archivo.php

Comment: Puedes usar `__DIR__` para referirte al mismo directorio del script,  por ejemplo: **`$file = __DIR__."backup/$fechaString"."backup.json";`**

Comment: @A.Cedano Nada, he intentado todas las posibles variables __DIR__, ./ , ../ pero me sigue saliendo este error PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(../backup/07-06-2021 19:45:35 backup.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPS\generarArchivo.php on line 9

Comment: Intenta con `dirname(__FILE__)` en lugar de `__DIR__` y dime si funciona.

Comment: Gracias por todo, pero nada. Me he fijado que la ruta del file_put_contents es correcta y el generarArchivo.php tambien se encuentra ahi

Comment: No puede ser. Muestra tu estructura de directorios, que se vea la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo donde está el script PHP con el que intentas guardar y que según tú es la misma carpeta donde está la carpeta `backup`

Comment: Prueba también así: **`$file = "/backup/$fechaString"."backup.json"`** poniendo `/` delante. Supongo que `generarArchivo.php`  se encuentra **fuera de `backup`**

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, tal cual asi la tengo, abajo te he pasado la captura

Comment: ¿Probaste también de este modo: **`$file = "/backup/$fechaString"."backup.json"`**?

Comment: Si, tambien he usado el dir antes de eso, el dirname y he cambiado los separadores por si acaso, pero nada.

Comment: @A.Cedano La he puesto arriba, era eso no?

Comment: ¿Qué arroja esto: `var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));` y esto: `var_dump(__DIR__);`?

Comment: Creo que olvidé un primer slash cuando te indiqué de usar `__DIR__`, prueba: **`$file = __DIR__."/backup/$fechaString"."backup.json";`**. Ufff por eso yo prefiero siempre definir constantes con mis rutas y luego usar esas constantes.

Comment: Lo mismo 'C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPS' Si, eso ya lo intente ponerle la barra esa y también el directory separator

Comment: $fechaString tiene la fecha y el tiempo, y con el tiempo separado por : ?  Ese sería un problema.