# ¿Como puedo evitar datos duplicados con una validación?

Tags: php, mysql, importación, phpspreadsheet

Estoy importando info de excel a una tabla de db , y quería preguntar como podría hacer una validación para evitar datos duplicados, intente con esto , pero me produce un error(HTTP ERROR 500) me funciona todo y me lo importa pero no logro hacer la validacion para evitar info duplicada , ejemplo :

```html
for ($indiceFila = 1; $indiceFila <= $numeroFilas; $indiceFila++) {
    $valorA = $hojaActual->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $indiceFila);
    $valorB = $hojaActual->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $indiceFila);
    if (!empty($valorA)) {
       $checkcod_duplicidad = "SELECT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='$valorA'";
        $ca_dupli = mysqli_query($con, $checkcod_duplicidad);
        $cant_duplicidad = mysqli_num_rows($ca_dupli);
        if ($cant_duplicidad == 0) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO productos(pr_nombre,pr_cantidad) VALUES('$valorA','$valorB')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        }
    }
    // $conexion->query($sql);
}
if ($result) {
    unlink($archivo);
    header("Location:form.php");
} else {

    unlink($archivo);
    header("Location:form.php");
}
```

PD : Estoy usando phpSpreadSheet

Comment: Porque haces la consulta de esta forma?  ```"SELECT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='" . ($valorA) . "' ");``` si haces un echo a esa consulta te traera algo estilo ```"SELECT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='(hola)' ");``` incluyendo los ```( )```, ya por alli esta fallando la consulta

Comment: @ernestojimenez Gracias por el detalle! Lo cambie de esta forma :             $checkcod_duplicidad = "SELECT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='$valorA'";

Comment: ¿Se resolvió tu problema? Si sigues teniendo un error 500, ese tipo de errores ocurre en el servidor y puede ser por algo tan simple como un carácter mal escrito o cosas más serias. Pon esto temporalmente al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`, guarda, prueba de nuevo y deberás ver en pantalla los errores ... copia/pega en la pregunta los mensajes de error que veas.

Comment: has probado usando distinct

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Recién lo probe, pero me mando el mismo error :/

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigooo Sos un grande! , gracias!, me fallaba la variable de conexion que lo tenia mal jajajaja, gracias!!, produje el distintic y arregle la variable de conexion y hay me resulto! Muchas Gracias!, me ayudo mucho los reportes de errores !!

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. No obstante las tres líneas de depuración que indiqué más arriba debes usarlas sólo **temporalmente**, cuando el código funcione debes quitar esas líneas. Lo mejor es que aprendas a depurar leyendo el log de errores de tu PHP, así sabrás siempre dónde y por qué falla el código. Si no depuras adecuadamente te puedes pasar horas y hasta semanas tratando de averiguar dónde ocurre el problema, cuando el log de error te dirá con exactitud qué problema es y dónde y te ayudará además a escribir un programa limpio, pues hay otros mensajes que no son errores ...

Comment: ... pero que *ensucian* el código y sobrecargan al servidor. Son mensajes del tipo `Warning` y otros, que no son errores fatales, pero si dejas código con este tipo de mensajes, puede que se estén escribiendo constantemente en el servidor, y todo eso tiene su precio en cada ejecución del programa. De hecho, puede que un archivo de log de errores tenga varios GB a lo largo del tiempo, por eso conviene conocer ese aspecto de la programación, por el que pocos se preocupan, pero que es fundamental de cara al rendimiento: depuras más rápido, y escribes un código limpio.

Comment: @A.Cedano La verdad encuentro mucha razon, últimamente me ha costado bastante ya que no he visto los errores que se producen , por lo cual me paso horas inclusive semanas viendo el error , y solo tenía que ver los reportes de errores, amigo no te imaginas la ayuda que me haz dado gracias! Un saludo!

Comment: Lo sé por experiencia y es algo en lo que siempre insisto: enseñar a depurar código debe ser una de las primeras cosas cuando aprendes a programar. La pérdida de tiempo depurando desanima, sobre todo cuando empiezas y no dominas el lenguaje, y es causa de abandono en muchos casos. Con respecto a PHP [abrí esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) hace un tiempo con el fin de ayudar a los nuevos programadores a conocer la forma de examinar los logs de errores, según el entorno PHP en que estén trabajando. Cuando conoces el error y dónde ocurre, ya te centras en él y punto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema por el cual se repita seguramente se deba a que no usas el `distinct` y esto lo que hace que se omite los valores repitidos, y solo lo muestra una vez.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='$valorA'"
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias Javie por tu aporte! Produje el cambio de esta forma :      if (!empty($valorA)) {
            $checkcod_duplicidad = "SELECT DISTINCT pr_nombre FROM productos WHERE pr_nombre='$valorA'";
            $ca_dupli = mysqli_query($con, $checkcod_duplicidad);
            $cant_duplicidad = mysqli_num_rows($ca_dupli);
            if ($cant_duplicidad == 0) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO productos(pr_nombre,pr_cantidad) VALUES('$valorA','$valorB')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            } Pero me salio el error http 500 pero si elimino los check

Comment: En ese caso si me funciona :/

Comment: entonces te funciona o no? y es necesario si o si el check?

Comment: Ignora eso amigo!! Muchas gracias! Me ayudaste! Resulta que no tenia bien la variable de conexion jajaj , eso me pasa por no ver los reportes de errores! Gracias!!!

Comment: de nada acuérdate de que si te ha ayudado de marcar la pregunta como positiva :)

Comment: Claro!! Muchas Gracias!