# Hacer un delete con curl

Tags: php, curl, postman

Estoy intentando hacer un DELETE mediante curl.

Viendo la documentación del proveedor me indica que primero tengo que obtener un token

> You will need to provide the CSRF token for all the POST/PUT/ DELETE requests.

Tengo hecha una función para devolverme el token mediante una llamada con GET

```
    public function getOOToken(){
     #Chequea los parámetros
    if (!isset($this->OOUserID) || !isset($this->OOPassword)) return false;

    #Compone la URL
    $url=$this->Config->_creap_1020_rest_url."available-languages";
            
    #Hace la llamada por Curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    $request_headers = array();
    $request_headers[] = 'X-CSRF-Token: Fetch';
    $request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->OOUserID.":".$this->OOPassword);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $header) use (&$headers)
        {
            $len  = strlen($header);
            $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
            if (count($header) < 2) { // ignore invalid headers
            return $len;
        }

        $name = strtolower(trim($header[0]));
        if (is_array($headers) && !array_key_exists($name, $headers)) {
            $headers[$name] = [trim($header[1])];
        } else {
            $headers[$name][] = trim($header[1]);
        }
        return $len;
    });  
    if (isset($this->OOTimeout) and is_numeric($this->OOTimeout)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->OOTimeout);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$request_headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    return $headers['x-csrf-token'][0];
    
}
```

Esta es la función que quiero que haga el DELETE

```
    public function deleteOOSchedule($id = Null) {
    $token = $this->getOOToken();
    #Chequea los parámetros
    if (!isset($this->OOUserID) || !isset($this->OOPassword)) return false;

    #Compone la URL
    $url=$this->Config->_creap_1020_rest_url."schedules/" . $id;
    
    #Hace la llamada por Curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->OOUserID.":".$this->OOPassword);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE"); 
    if (isset($this->OOTimeout) and is_numeric($this->OOTimeout)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->OOTimeout);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
         'x-csrf-token: ' . $token, "Content-Type: application/json"
     ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch)
        return $result;
}
```

Pero no me devuelve nada.

He probado utilizando Postman

Y poniendo la url con GET me devuelve el X-CSRF-TOKEN

Y luego en la url que quiero enviarla como DELETE le pongo el token en Authoriztion Bearer Token sin hacer nada tampoco

¿alguna idea?

Comment: que es hacer nada?? debe haver un log o un error ... algo en la pestaña de red o de consola del navegador o en el servidor apache que ejecuta el pho ...

Comment: como se supone que debemos reproducir el error para darte una respuesta?

Comment: es imposible si no conocemos tampoco el codigo que consumes con curl que es lo que espera que se envie de manera efectiva esa url.

Comment: Añade un control de errores a tu código y dinos qué error da. Es tan simple como esto: `if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}` No trabajes a ciegas, los lenguajes de programación tiene algo que se llama log de errores, [debes consultarlos cuando algo falla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967). Hay quienes pierden días rompiéndose el coco cuando algo falla en el programa y se preguntan qué será. Hay que ir al log de errores.