# Como observar proyecto MVC hecho con PHP a Cpanel

Tags: php, mvc

Cordial Saludo.

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y he realizado un proyecto con MVC. Lo he terminado y lo subí a mi servidor real, no es localhost, pero en el momento que accedo a la url (https://midominio/barbershop/) no se observa. El archivo principal index.php, se encuentra en la carpeta public; como hago para acceder al archivo y que no se vea esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acudo a ustedes que tienen experiencia y mayor conocimiento para que me guíen.
Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: ¿Tienes el intérprete de PHP funcionando en el servidor?

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, ¿Pero a cual intérprete de PHP hace referencia?

Comment: Parece que no tienes bien las redirecciones y te está listando los archivos que hay en la carpeta `barbershop`, cosa muy peligrosa en entornos remotos. Deberías tirar de `.htaccess` para evitar que se listen los archivos, y redirigir a un archivo `index.php` que haga de punto de entrada en tu web, lanzando desde él las rutas y demás.

Comment: Tengo el archivo .htacces dentro de la carpeta Public. ¿La saco y la dejo en la raiz del proyecto?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si entras a `https://midominio/barbershop/public/index.php`?

Comment: Para saber si tienes PHP funcionando, se crea un archivo de nombre cualquiera con extensión php, este archivo tendrá que ser visible desde un navegador, considera ponerlo en `public_html`. El contenido de dicho archivo es `<?php
phpinfo(); ?>` Luego al acceder, podrás ver 1 de 2: Si tienes el intérprete de PHP funcionando en el server y está activado, verás una serie de tablas con información de lo que hay instalado, datos de sistema y demás; en caso no tengas el intérprete instalado y/o desactivado, solo verás texto plano con contenido: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que no tienes bien las redirecciones y te está listando los archivos que hay en la carpeta `barbershop`, cosa muy peligrosa en entornos remotos. Deberías tirar de `.htaccess` para evitar que se listen los archivos, y redirigir a un archivo `index.php` que haga de punto de entrada en tu web, lanzando desde él las rutas y demás.

En principio, con esto debería funcionar, salvo que tengas más errores o cosas mal ubicadas.

**1. Archivo `.htaccess` en la carpeta `barbershop`**

Crea un archivo llamado **`.htaccess`** en la carpeta `barbershop` con este contenido como mínimo:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Esto hará que cualquier petición hecho a `barbershop` sea mandada al archivo `index.php`.

Más cosas se pueden hacer desde ese archivo...

**2. Archivo `index.php`**

Crea, si no lo tienes, un archivo `index.php` en la carpeta `barbershop`. Como ya en (1) dijiste que todo intento de acceso a esa carpeta será redirigido al archivo `index.php`, ahora sólo te falta controlar las rutas y demás desde el archivo `index.php`.

En `index.php` vas a recibir todas las peticiones: GET, POST, etc, podrás descifrarlas con `PATH_INFO` y podrás enrutarlas, eso ya dependiendo del estilo de programación que estés implementando.

#### Post-Data

Ahora ya puedes navegar a direcciones como:

```
https://www.midominio.com/barbershop/users/all
```

Y en `index.php` vas a recibir los parámetros de la petición: `user` y `all`, que, en un entorno bien programado significará, **todos los usuarios** y mandarás a buscar todos los usuarios.

Si no funciona, revisa el log de errores y nos dices. Y si no sabes revisar el log de errores, pues aprende, te ahorrará muuuchos problemas. Mientras, este pequeño truco sirve: colocar al inicio de `index.php` algo como esto:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Esto, úsalo sólo de forma provisional, te monstrará en pantalla todos los errores. Pero no te acostumbres a ello, aprende a mirar en el log de errores.

Revisa la pregunta *[Quiero revisar el registro de errores de PHP, ¿dónde lo encuentro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967)* para más detalles sobre el log de errores.

Comment: Gracias por el tiempo para explicarme. Seguire su consejo, pues me encuentro en aprendizaje.

Comment: @Brayammartinezperdomo y no, no conviene sacar el archivo `.htaccess` de la carpeta `public`, cada carpeta puede tener su propio `.htaccess` y puede que `public` necesite sus propias reglas. Si quitas el archivo de `public` puede que la carpeta root de tu servidor quede expuesta.

Comment: Gracias, seguí todas las indicaciones y funciono perfectamente. Voy a realizar otra pregunta, por favor revisala y me comentas.