# Problema con el menú

Tags: wordpress, web, menú

quería preguntar en esta comunidad lo siguiente: mi web es lenta y cuando quiero acceder a las secciones del menú que tiene no me accede a la sección. Adjunto una foto para explicarme mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me preguntaba si hay otra opción que no sea restaurar a una copia de seguridad anterior, ya que mi sitio web es de noticias y si restauro a una copia anterior mis entradas se eliminarían (Noticias). Gracias

Intenté vaciar el caché, reparar la base de datos, cambiar las versiones de php y nada.

Comment: La versión de php, el numero de complementos, el numero de archivos js y css, el numero de request que se hacen y la calidad del servidor, hay un monton de cosas que pueden afectar la velocidad de tu web, tu pregunta es muy amplia, debes de ser más especifico con tu problema, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: La solución no es volver a un estado anterior donde tu web no era lenta, sino descubrir por qué motivo empezó a ser lenta y corregir lo que causa esa lentitud. El abanico de posibilidades es muy amplio. Por ejemplo, un modelo de datos mal diseñado que a partir de una cierta cantidad de filas en la base de datos empezó a quejarse; restricciones en el servidor que aloja la web, el cual te exige que a partir de un cierto tráfico pases a un plan más costoso; un plugin que instalaste y que ha ralentizado todo; un código no optimizado; etc.

Comment: Olvidé decir que por lo general (a no ser que esté desactivado, cosa no recomendable) los servidores guardan información sobre fallos, advertencias, etc, en un archivo de errores (log de errores). Cuando un sitio empieza a ser lento, una de las primeras fuentes a consultar sería ese log de errores, el cual se guarda de modos distintos, según cada entorno. Puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) para más detalles. Y, no es por asustar, pero otra causa de lentitud en un sitio podría ser un hackeo, en tu propio sitio, o en el servidor compartido si es el caso

Answer (score 0):

Además de todo lo que te dijeron en [los](/q/606413/606417#comment1069974_606413) [comentarios](/q/606413/606417#comment1069976_606413), también es importante usar imágenes comprimidas y que no necesiten muchos recursos para cargar.

Puedes ayudarte de estos y muchos otros consejos con la [herramienta de desarrollo de Google](https://pagespeed.web.dev), que analiza tu página web en busca de problemas de rendimiento. O también con el modo inspección (F12 en Windows y otros sistemas operativos) y el apartado "LightHouse", el cual te da la misma opción que la página web con alguna que otra ventaja.