# Problema en proyecto PHP con arquitectura MVC

Tags: php, mvc

estoy haciendo un curso de PHP en YouTube y en el curso se utiliza el modelo MVC. Mi problema es que no estoy pudiendo traer vistas. Para eso tengo un controlador llamado "Controller" en el cual tengo una condicional y un else, siempre que trato de traer una vista desde cualquier lado del proyecto el controlador se va por else y no puedo determinar la causa, yo necesito que la condición se cumpla para así poder traer la vista con éxito y que se imprima en pantalla lo solicitado. Por este problema que estoy experimentando estoy algo desmotivado y el curso se me esta haciendo muy pesado porque al no poder traer las vistas solo me limito a escribir el código sin poder corroborar si todo se imprime como debería, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, desde ya, gracias.
Esto es lo que tengo en mi archivo "Controller":

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Controller{
    public function view($route, $data = []){
    
        //Destructurar el array
        extract($data);

        $route = str_replace('.', '/', $route);

        if(file_exists("../resources/views/{$route}.php")){

            ob_start();
            include "../resources/views/{$route}.php";
            $content = ob_get_clean();
            
            return $content;

        }else{
            return "El archivo no existe";
        }
    }

    public function redirect($route){
        header("Location: {$route}");
    }
```

}[image: Directorio del proyecto:]

Comment: Es muy simple. Escribiste el nombre del directorio con una `s` en vez de una `c`. Tienes `resourses` cuando debería ser **`resources`**, por eso no encuentra las vistas. Para que no te desmotives, [aprende a depurar el código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967). Te ahorrará horas en la programación y muchos desánimos que a veces vienen por problemas muy simples.

Comment: Es cierto, pensaba que lo tenia bien escrito y ese era el problema, muchas gracias! Estoy aprendiendo todavía y me ayuda mucho saber que hay gente dispuesta a ayudar hasta en los errores mas tontos, jajá, Hace como 3 días estaba tratando de solucionarlo.

Comment: se llaman errrores typograficos y son bastante comunes...

Comment: Pues lo dicho, aprende a usar el log de errores y te ahorrarás horas / días / semanas o incluso tirar la toalla. Los mensajes de error suelen estar en inglés, pero se suele entender lo que quieren decir aún sin ser experto en inglés. En cuanto a las rutas, te recomendaría que las definas como constantes en un solo archivo, así el código queda más independiente y más fácil de mantener y se evitan errores tipográficos al tener que escribirlas cada vez.