# Problema al realizar inserciones en la base de datos utilizando PHP y PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que necesito realizar inserciones de datos en una base de datos PostgreSQL mediante PHP. Sin embargo, estoy experimentando dificultades y no puedo lograr que las inserciones se completen con éxito.

He configurado la conexión a la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

**PÁGINA DE ALTAS**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VaidrollTeamLogin6</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagina de registro 2.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cajafuera" align="center">
        <div class="formulariocaja" align="center">
            <form method="post" action="" name="vaidrollteam">
                <div class="formtitulo">Registrate</div>

                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="text" name="Nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre:" class="cajaentradatexto">
                    <input type="text" name="Apellidos" placeholder="Ingresar apellidos:" class="cajaentradatexto">
                </div>

                <div class="input-container-2">
                    <input type="text" name="Edad" placeholder="Edad:" class="cajaentradatexto">
                    <input type="text" name="Peso" placeholder="Peso:" class="cajaentradatexto">  
                    <input type="text" name="Estatura" placeholder="Estatura:" class="cajaentradatexto">
                </div>

                <div class="input-container-3">
                    <input type="text" name="Edad" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" class="cajaentradatexto_nombre_de_usuario">
                </div>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="text" name="Correo" placeholder="Ingresar correo:" class="cajaentradatexto_nombre_de_usuario">
                </div>

                <div class="input-container">
                    <input type="password" name="Contraseña" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña:" class="cajaentradatexto">
                </div>

                <div class="botondeprueba">
                    <a type="submit" type="button" href="Loggin.html" >Registrarse</a> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**BASE DE DATOS**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  ide SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre text NOT NULL,
  Apellidos text NOT NULL,
  Usuario varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  Correo text NOT NULL,
  Contraseña text NOT NULL,
  Sexo char,
  Edad integer NOT NULL,
  Peso double precision NOT NULL,
  Estatura double precision NOT NULL
  Imagen text
);
```

ALTAS (PHP)

```
//Conexión a la base de datos

<?php

$host = "localhost";
$port = "5432";
$dbname = "usuarios";
$user = "postgres"; 
$password = "319011340";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;user=$user;password=$password");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['Apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $correo = $_POST['Correo'];
    $contraseña = $_POST['Contraseña'];
    $edad = $_POST['Edad'];
    $peso = $_POST['Peso'];
    $estatura = $_POST['Estatura'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre, Apellidos, Usuario, Correo, Contraseña, Edad, Peso, Estatura) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $correo, $contraseña, $edad, $peso, $estatura]);

    // Redirige a una página de éxito
    header("Location: pagina principal.html");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Manejo de errores, redirige a una página de error
    header("Location: Loggin.html");
}

?>
```

**CONEXION**

```
<?php

$host='localhost';
$port='5432';
$dbname='Base de datos 1';
$user='postgres';
$password='319011340';

$conexion=pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$bd user=$user password=$pass");

?>
```

**VALIDACIÓN**

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

session_start();

$usuario=$_POST['txtusuario'];
$clave=$_POST['txtpassword'];

$query=("SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE 
Usuario='$usuario' AND Contraseña='$clave");

$consulta=pg_query($conexion,$query);
$cantidad=pg_num_rows($consulta);

if ($cantidad>0){

    $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$usuario;
    header('Location:ingreso.php');
}
else{
    echo "Datos Incorrectos";
}
```

Sin embargo, no importa lo que haga, no puedo lograr que la inserción sea exitosa. No estoy recibiendo errores ni mensajes de éxito, lo que dificulta el diagnóstico del problema. ¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal? ¿Hay alguna manera de depurar este problema de inserción de datos?

Agradecería cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para solucionar este problema y poder realizar inserciones en mi base de datos PostgreSQL mediante PHP.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

De momento sigo teniendo errores al momento de hacer la conexión de la base de datos con el sitio web pero he corregido los errores en el código.

**BASE DE DATOS**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  ide SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre text NOT NULL,
  Apellidos text not null,
  Usuario char (20) NOT NULL,
  Correo text NOT NULL,
  Contrasena text NOT NULL,
  Sexo char,
  Edad integer NOT NULL,
  Peso double precision NOT NULL,
  Estatura double precision NOT NULL
);
```

**ALTAS**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host = "localhost";
$port = "5432";
$dbname = "DB1";
$user = "postgres"; 
$password = "319011340";

    $nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['Apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
    $correo = $_POST['Correo'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['Contrasena'];
    $edad = $_POST['Edad'];
    $peso = $_POST['Peso'];
    $estatura = $_POST['Estatura'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (Nombre, Apellidos, Usuario, Correo, Contrasena, Edad, Peso, Estatura) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$nombre, $apellidos, $usuario, $correo, $contrasena, $edad, $peso, $estatura]);

?>
```

**CONEXION**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host='localhost';
$port='5432';
$dbname='DB1';
$user='postgres';
$password='319011340';

$conexion=pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$bd user=$user password=$pass");

?>
```

**VALIDACION**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'conexion.php';

session_start();

$usuario=$_POST['txtusuario'];
$clave=$_POST['txtpassword'];

$query=("SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE 
Usuario='$usuario' AND Contrasena='$clave");

$consulta=pg_query($conexion,$query);
$cantidad=pg_num_rows($consulta);

if ($cantidad>0){

    $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$usuario;
    header('Location:ingreso.php');
}
else{
    echo "Datos Incorrectos";
}
```

**INGRESO**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];
echo 'Loggin.html';

?>
```

Comment: [Revisa el log de errores de PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967). Si quieres ver **provisionalmente** en pantalla lo que está pasando, puedes agregar estas tres líneas al inicio de los archivos `.php` que estarían fallando: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Pero lo mejor es que **ubiques el log de errores y lo revises cada vez que algo ande mal**. Así evitas poner las tres líneas esas por todos lados. Por otro lado, evita usar `ñ` y acentos en nombres de variables, o de tablas / columnas.

Comment: Hola Robzoly, así de pasada te diría que tenes un error en `ALTAS` ya que estas definiendo `$dbname = "usuarios";` pero en `CONEXION` utilizas `$dbname='Base de datos 1';`. ¿Por qué en un lugar usas `PDO` y en el otro `PostgreSQL`? Deberías decidirte por uno.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si no vas a ayudar, de verdad te pido de la forma más amable que solamente no entorpezcas mi trabajo. Soy muy nuevo en la programación de sistemas de información y la verdad me encuentro muchas trabas.

Comment: @Marcos Ya corregí los errores de las **ALTAS** y de la **Conexion** por lo que sigo teniendo errores, y no entiendo la diferencia entre PDO y PostgreSQL

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por tus observaciones y al menos ya tengo idea de como ver los errores, a pesar de seguir teniéndolos al menos ya puedo identificarlos

Comment: Si el código sigue sin funcionar conviene que agregues a la pregunta los mensajes de error. Así podremos localizarlos y ayudarte a resolverlos con mayor rapidez. Sin eso, tendríamos que analizar toda la lógica del programa y luego tratar de adivinar, porque no tenemos a mano un escenario de prueba completo.

Comment: No se de PHP, pero cuando haces la conexión las variables que usas para conectarte y las que estableces son diferentes, no estará ahí el problema?