# tengo un formulario quiero insertar los datos a una tabla pero no lo envia a la tabla

Tags: php

```
   formulario:
       <form action="procesar_entrada.php" method="POST">
       <!-- Campo select para id_cliente -->
                <div> 
                      <label>Seleccione el producto</label> 
                      <br>
                     <select name="nombre">
                     <?php
                     $producto_query = "SELECT * FROM producto";
                     $producto_result = $conn->query($producto_query);
                     while($row = $producto_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['nombre'] . " 
                    </option>";
                     }
                     ?>
                     </select>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cantidad a ingresar</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" name="entradas">
                    </div>
                                            
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Observacion</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="observacion">
                    </div>

            <!-- Campo oculto para id_usuario -->
         <input name="id_usuario" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; ? 
            >">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
         <a href="entradas_aux.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
          </form>
```

procesar la entrada para enviarla a la tabla:

```
         <?php 
         session_start(); 

         // Validaciones 
        $id_usuario = isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"]) ? 
        intval($_SESSION["id_usuario"]) : exit("Usuario no logueado");
        // Suponiendo que estas variables deberían provenir de algún 
        formulario o alguna otra fuente de datos

         $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; // Cambia 'nombre' por el nombre 
         correcto del campo
         $entradas = $_POST['entradas']; // Cambia 'entradas' por el 
          nombre correcto del campo
          $observacion = $_POST['observacion']; // Cambia 'observacion' 
          por el nombre correcto del campo

       // Luego de recibir los valores, puedes verificar si están 
       definidos y no son nulos
       if(isset($nombre) && isset($entradas) && isset($observacion)) 
        {
       // Tu código para la inserción en la base de datos aquí
       } else {
       exit("Ocurrió un error: Algunos datos no fueron 
       proporcionados"); // Manejo de errores si los datos no están 
       presentes
        }



     include_once "base_de_datos.php"; 

      // Aquí asumimos que ya has iniciado la sesión y verificado que 
        el usuario está logueado 

        $ahora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

         try { 
         $base_de_datos->beginTransaction(); 

         $sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO 
      entradas(nombre, entradas, observacion, id_usuario, fecha) 
       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"); 
       $sentencia->execute([$nombre, $entradas, $observacion, 
        $id_usuario, $ahora]); 

        $sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("SELECT id FROM entradas 
         ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"); 
         $sentencia->execute(); 
         $resultado = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

 

         $sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO 
          producto(existencia) VALUES (?);"); 
          $sentenciaExistencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("UPDATE 
           producto SET existencia = existencia - ? WHERE id = ?;"); 

           foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $producto) { 
           // Asegúrate de que 'total' y 'cantidad' son valores 
              numéricos válidos 
              $sentencia->execute([$producto->id, $producto- 
               >entradas]); 
           $sentenciaExistencia->execute([$producto->entradas, 
         $producto->id]); 
         } 

         $base_de_datos->commit(); 
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
     $base_de_datos->rollBack(); 
     exit("Ocurrió un error: " . $e->getMessage()); 
    } 

     unset($_SESSION["carrito"]); 
     $_SESSION["carrito"] = []; 
     header("Location: entradas_aux.php?status=1"); 
     ?>
```

me falta que los datos se guarden en la tabla,la funcion del codigo es que guarde los datos ingresados en el formulario en la tabla entradas y a su vez con el input de entradas que actualice y agrege la cantidad ingresada en el stock de los productos, las entradas es para llevar un control de los productos que compraron cuantos productos y eso se tiene que guardar en la tabla producto y actualizar solo el stock(existencia),cuando en las variables le coloco 1 funciona el codigo pero al colocarlo en metodo post para que guarde el valor enviado del formulario no resive nada, el formulario no esta enviado a procesar_ventas.php y tambien da este error Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\procesar_entrada.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: entradas in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\procesar_entrada.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: observacion in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\procesar_entrada.php on line 10
Ocurrió un error: Algunos datos no fueron proporcionados, estare esperando su respuesta gracias

Comment: Hola. ¿Este código muestra algún error u otro tipo de mensaje en pantalla?

Comment: no ninguno lo cual lo hace mas dificil saber que esta fallando

Comment: ¿Tampoco redirige a ningún lado? ¿Sabes cómo [revisar el log de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967)?

Comment: a ningun lado, el log de errores nop

Comment: intentaste imprimir en pantalla la información que te llega? ademas, que longitud o que tipo de dato es el campo fecha en tu base de datos?

Comment: nop, como ya ese codigo lo use para insertar otro dato y funcionaba pero al modificarlo para ese formulario ya no hace nada y la fecha la verdad no se

Comment: Revisa el log de errores. ¿El archivo php donde tienes el  código de abajo está en la misma carpeta que el archivo donde tienes el formulario?

Comment: sip esta en la misma carpeta

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Ya me extrañaba que no hubiera ningún mensaje por ninguna parte. Considera revisar tu log de errores siempre y agregar a la pregunta los mensajes de error o las advertencias o noticias. Dicho eso, ¿qué tipo de conexión estás usando? En el código de arriba usas `mysqli` y en el de abajo `PDO`. Son dos herramientas distintas. Muéstranos cómo conectas en `base_de_datos.php` enmascarando datos sensibles. Y, para evitar los *Undefined index* considera usar `isset`, ternarios o fusión de null para verificar los datos antes de pasar a usarlos.

Comment: A donde envías tu formulario, simplemente imprime primero tus variables para ver si lo estás enviando bien. `<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
$entradas = $_POST['entradas']; 
$observacion = $_POST['observacion'];

echo $nombre." y ".$entradas." y ".$observacion;

?>`

Comment: ya lo imprimi no me muestra nada sigue el mismo error

Comment: base_de_datos.php <?php $contraseña = "";
$usuario = "root";
$nombre_base_de_datos = "registro";
try{
 $base_de_datos = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $nombre_base_de_datos, $usuario, $contraseña);
  $base_de_datos->query("set names utf8;");
    $base_de_datos->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $base_de_datos->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $base_de_datos->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo "Ocurrió algo con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>