# Problema con .send(); de Btn.onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

ante todo muchas gracias, como novato que soy acudo mucho a este foro y me ayudan mucho a resolver mis dudas.

Tengo el siguiente codigo de login de un chat y no logro entender porque en servidor local funciona correctamente pero subiendolo a servidor para testear (000webhost) me da el siguiente error:

500 (Internal Server Error)
continueBtn.onclick @ login.js:27

login.js:

```
continueBtn = form.querySelector(".button input"),
errorText = form.querySelector(".error-text");

form.onsubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
}

continueBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/login.php", true);
    xhr.onload = ()=>{
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
              let data = xhr.response;
              if(data === "success"){
                location.href = "users.php";
              }else{
                errorText.style.display = "block";
                errorText.textContent = data;
              }
          }
      }
    }
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

El archivo php/login.php si existe en el servidor

en el inspeccionador de elementos de chrome me marca el error en xhr.send(formData);

Gracias de antemano y feliz nuevo año

Actualizo

php/login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "config.php";
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios WHERE email = '{$email}'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $user_pass = $password;
        $enc_pass = $row['password'];
        if ($user_pass === $enc_pass) {
            $status = "Disponible";
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tb_usuarios SET status = '{$status}' WHERE id = {$row['id']}");
            if ($sql2) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                echo "Proceso Exitoso";
            } else {
                echo "Algo salió mal. ¡Inténtalo de nuevo!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "¡Correo electrónico o la contraseña son incorrectos!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "$email - ¡Este correo electrónico no existe!";
    }
} else {
    echo "¡Todos los campos de entrada son obligatorios!";
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Cristian, ese error suele estar relacionado con la parte del backend, es decir, en tu caso con el archivo "php/login.php"; podrías compartir el código de ese archivo?

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida, ya actualicé agregando el phph/login.php

Comment: a simple vista no veo ningun error en el codigo php podrias verificar el log de errores del server apache y php a ver que registro???

Comment: A simple vista, `login.php` no parece tener ningún error desde el punto de vista sintáctico. ¿Quizá el error está en `config.php`? Si hubieras [revisado el registro de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967), ya habrías detectado con precisión dónde está el problema.