# No funciona El bucle foreach en Page-Template de Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, foreach

Parece que ha habido una actualización de PHP que desconozco

En la carpeta page-template del tema (hecho por mi personalizado) hay un archivo para poner una plantilla personalizada para poner seis tarjetas cuyos datos tomo de un archivo json mediante un bucle Foreach.

El bucle Foreach funcionaba antes pero ahora no funciona. Tal vez sea una actualización de PHP que desconozco.

Reemplazando las tarjetas puse seis textos idénticos.

Puedes ver esto [aquí](https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/). El texto anterior se ingresa directamente en el editor de WordPress.

Este es el código:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Cards Principal */
?>
<?php get_post(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<hr>
<h2 class="pageTitle"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h2>
<hr>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php

$miJSON = file_get_contents(
  'https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/wp-content/uploads/json/principal.json'
);
$datos = json_decode($miJSON, true);

echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
echo '<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-4">';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';
echo '<strong>TARJETA EN MANTENIMIENTO</strong>';

foreach($datos as $dato){
  echo '<a href="' . $dato['Enlace'] . '" target="_blank">';
  echo '<div class="card text-center">';
  echo '<img src="' . $dato['url_imagen'] .
    '" class="card-img-top"  alt="' . $dato['Título'] . '">';
  echo '<div class="card-body">';
  echo '<h3 class="card-title">' . $dato['Título'] . '</h3>';
  echo '<p class="card-text">'.$dato['Texto'].'</p>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</a>';
}

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué significa exactamente *no funciona* en este caso? ¿Revisaste el log de errores para ver lo que está fallando?

Comment: A través del bucle Foreach deberían aparecer impresas 6 cards cuyos datos están en un archivo json. Hasta hoy funcionaba bien, pero ahora no

Comment: No revise lo los errores de log. Mañana lo haré  porque ahora estoy desde el móvil. Eso ¿supongo que se hace con el inspector de elementos?

Comment: No, eso se hace entrando a los archivos del servidor, vía consola o vía un cliente de sftp. Supongo que tendrás algún modo de editar los archivos, pues desde ese cliente puedes revisar el log de errores o en su defecto activar temporalmente el modo Debug de Wordpress para ir al problema directamente.

Comment: Los archivos los tengo alojados en en el hosting y los puedo editar fácilmente. Lo de revisar el log de errores y lo del Debug ya me enteraré  mañana haber como se hace. Gracias y un sa

Comment: Gracias y un saludo. Mañana más

Comment: Dado que, dependiendo del sistema operativo del servidor o de la configuración del hosting el log de errores puede estar desactivado y/o en ubicaciones diferentes de la habitual, te dejo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) donde se explican procedimientos adecuados para identificar dicho archivo. Ten en cuenta que si vas a desarrollar en `.php`, conocer este archivo y consultarlo cuando algo falle, te va a ahorrar muchísimo tiempo a la hora de identificar problemas, pudiendo corregirlos con mayor rapidez. Es una herramienta que no debería ser ignorada.

Comment: Acabo de hacer el debug y sale esto:

Comment: [10-Jan-2024 08:22:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /home/bfsxnvop/public_html/wp-content/themes/tema_personalizado/page-template/decadas.php on line 17

Comment: La línea 17 de decadas.php es esta: foreach($datos as $dato){

Comment: Los mensajes de error deben ir en la pregunta. El mensaje te está diciendo que ese objeto es nulo. Entonces, depura ese objeto y revisa por qué es nulo. Pon un `var_dump($datos);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Ya hice un var_dump($datos) y sale NULL

Comment: En mi contexto el código funciona perfectamente, entonces, debe haber algo en tu entorno que hace que `$datos` sea `NULL`. Revisa más líneas en el log de errores para ver si aparece allí alguna pista. Una pregunta, ¿el dominio desde el cual usas este código está en `https`?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `allow_url_fopen` debe estar activado para que `file_get_contents()` funcione con archivos externos. Para una verificación rápida puedes agregar esto provisionalmente: **`echo ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) ?  'Activado' : 'Desactivado';`** Si ves `Desactivado` entonces ya tienes el motivo de por qué no funciona y deberías activar `allow_url_fopen`  en tu `php.ini`, o bien usar [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) en vez de `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Si, es https://

Comment: echo ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) ?  'Activado' : 'Desactivado';  Me pone Activado

Comment: Pues debes buscar alguna pista en el log de errores. No veo más motivos para que no funcione. Lo he probado en mi entorno y funciona perfectamente. O bien intenta con cURL.

Comment: ChatGPT me dice que introduca estas líneas:

Comment: if ($datos === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    echo 'Error al decodificar el JSON: ' . json_last_error_msg();
    // Puedes agregar más lógica aquí según sea necesario.
} else {

Comment: Y me sale: Error al decodificar el JSON: Syntax error

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($miJSON);` y verifica la salida. Parece que no estás manejando bien la codificación en ese entorno y está recibiendo la respuesta con caracteres que rompen el JSON.

Comment: He probado el código y funciona correctamente tanto en local como en WP.

Comment: He puesto var_dump($miJSON) y sale directamente en texto el archivo json

Comment: O sea que redirige a https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/wp-content/uploads/json/principal.json

Comment: ese foreach solo recorre el primer nivel y en el primer nivel solo hay: `0 =>array, 1 => array`

Comment: yo haria also asi: https://onlinephp.io/c/74a38

Comment: Pero debes revisar el texto, viendo que no haya caracteres extraños. Sospecho que en tu caso el contenido está llegando con codificación que rompe el JSON. Para descartar eso, puedes copiar el resultado del `var_dump` sin la comilla inicial y la final, y tratar de validarlo pegándolo en [este validador en línea](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) o en otro.

Answer (score 2):

Por fin ya esta solucionado. Agradecido a todos los que se molestaron y fueron contestando este hilo para intentar solucionar el problema. En el código simplemente se convierte el json en array

```php
<?php
/* Template Name: Cards Principal */
?>
<?php get_post(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<hr>
<h2 class="pageTitle"><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h2>
<hr>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
```

```
// este es el metodo file_get_content json_decode (ya no funciona)
// $miJSON = file_get_contents('https://archivo.json');
// $datos = json_decode($miJSON, true);

// Pasos para insertat el Json:
// 1. Crear una tabla en Tablepress y descargarla en csv
// 2. Convertir el csv a json aquí: https://csvjson.com/csv2json
// 3. Insertar el json resultante aquí:
// https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ y hacer click en PROCESS
// 4. Hacer click en el icono de las dos flechas opuestas (Convert JSON)
// 5. Nos va a llevar a esta página:
// https://dataconverter.curiousconcept.com/# y hacer click en CONVERT
// 6. Al final nos sacará un un array que es
//    el que vamos a pegar aquí a continuación
```

```php
/* ---vv--- */

$array = array (
  0 => array (
    'Título' => 'Décadas',
    'Texto' => 'Listado de películas clasificadas por periodos de 10 años',
    'Enlace' => 'https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/decadas/',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ecGP-LxKkbkFq_8Xj-HSaaqD6NCngVFnvq5KocZB59GrRn9_bK7xXvwTOd3kB9CkY2g=w1920-h1080',
  ),
  1 => array (
    'Título' => 'Biografías',
    'Texto' => 'Trayectoria vital de cada uno de los personajes que hicieron posible la existencia del cine',
    'Enlace' => 'https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/biografias/',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/Fsq7PJ05MZ2c6E1lmTA8kTsAmkbxwH2JtBaT-CzjDiHuXr2tITfE3aKs4RaZ_9APabE=w1920-h1080',
  ),
  2 => array (
    'Título' => 'Sagas',
    'Texto' => 'Agrupaciones de películas que siguen una misma trama a lo largo del tiempo',
    'Enlace' => 'https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/sagas/',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/SdHFz1snnBHp7LiCeIiT5BCIBtpurVVXh2AW0Hm35qy3wT9VPEwaaW1nk50zBJI43JM=w1920-h1080',
  ),
  3 => array (
    'Título' => '2000 canciones siglo XX',
    'Texto' => 'El siglo XX no solo destacó por su cine, sino también por su música',
    'Enlace' => 'https://2000cancionessigloxx.com/',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/XaYDS_TTdsmJ_61Pt5Rr4K1_Dzx-3jnEvs2yXGT3txeB7rF-edFDe-jNznAl5XY=w1920-h1080',
  ),
  4 => array (
    'Título' => 'Tienda AMAZON',
    'Texto' => 'Si eres amante del cine clásico, aprovecha para adquirir productos relacionados en la tienda más grande del mundo',
    'Enlace' => 'https://tienda.2000peliculassigloxx.com/',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/8GBUwKeQggIIGeYBEgFFr01WzKE3ZG9crJHhxX1-sLsSJ2lalFnQQjMkPSs=w2400',
  ),
  5 => array (
    'Título' => 'Merchandising',
    'Texto' => 'Puedes ayudar a esta web adquiriendo divertidas camisetas',
    'Enlace' => 'https://www.positivos.com/user/2000peliculassigloxx',
    'url_imagen' => 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/XRph3nlGvWHVAGnGinxYgCSz-_XgKDxJe86qE8k2Kjn-P4sWGEFGlx69eXQ=w2400',
  ),
);

/* ---^^--- */

echo '<div class="container-fluid">';^
echo '<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-4">';

foreach($array as $key => $dato){
  echo '<a href="' . $dato['Enlace'] . '" target="_blank">';
  echo '<div class="card text-center">';
  echo '<img src="' . $dato['url_imagen'] .
    '" class="card-img-top"  alt="' . $dato['Título'] . '">';
  echo '<div class="card-body">';
  echo '<h3 class="card-title">' . $dato['Título'] . '</h3>';
  echo '<p class="card-text">' . $dato['Texto'] . '</p>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</a>';
}

echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Os dejo como ha quedado definitivamente con sus comentarios respectivos. Tal vez esto os pueda servir para vuestros proyectos

Comment: Anotar solamente que si en algún momento el contenido de `https://2000peliculassigloxx.com/wp-content/uploads/json/principal.json` cambiase, esos cambios no se van a reflejar en tu código, donde solamente estás trasladando **manualmente, en otro tipo de estructura** el contenido actual de ese archivo.

Answer (score -1):

Si ya estás usando el plugin [TablePress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tablepress/) para armar la lista, podes usar las funciones del mismo plugin para obtener y recorrer los datos.

- verificar si una tabla existe:

[`TablePress::$model_table->table_exists($table_id)`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tablepress/trunk/controllers/controller-frontend.php#L516)

- cargar los datos de una tabla:

[`$table = TablePress::$model_table->load($table_id, true, true);`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tablepress/trunk/controllers/controller-frontend.php#L530)

El array devuelto tiene las `options` para esa tabla, si está marcada la opción de que la primer fila contiene los títulos/nombres de las columnas ( opción predeterminada ) : `1 == $table['options']['table_head']` tomas esa primer fila para obtener los keys de un array asociativo.

En este caso usando el snippet de ["How to convert to array with keys from first row"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685544/1423096) y así obtener un array como el que generaste exportando, copiando y pegando.

Con un par de `if`s para ver si el plugin esta activo y si la tabla tiene datos quedaría algo así:

```php
<?php

// id de la tabla : ver shortcode [table id=1]
$table_id = 1;

if (
  class_exists('TablePress')
  && property_exists('TablePress', 'model_table')
  && method_exists(TablePress::$model_table, 'load')
) {
  /* 
  La clase y el method existen ( tablepress 2.2.4 )
  TablePress::$model_table->load 
  */

  // https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tablepress/trunk/controllers/controller-frontend.php#L516
  /* si la tabla con $table_id existe */

  if (TablePress::$model_table->table_exists($table_id)) {

    // https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tablepress/trunk/controllers/controller-frontend.php#L530
    /* cargamos la tabla con sus opciones */

    $table = TablePress::$model_table->load($table_id, true, true);

    if (
      !is_wp_error($table)
      && !($table['is_corrupted'] ?? false)
      && !empty($table['data'] ?? [])
    ) {
      /*
      si: no hubo error de wp
          y no esta la tabla marcada como corrupta  
          y no esta vacía la tabla 
      */


      /* verificar si la primera fila son los títulos de las columnas */
      $table_head = (1 == $table['options']['table_head'] ?? '');
      $table_data = $table['data'];


      /* 
      first row as array keys
      https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685544/1423096
      */

      if ($table_head) {
        /* usar primera fila como keys */
        $headings = array_shift($table_data);
      } else {
        /* sino definir keys */
        $headings = ['Título', 'Texto', 'Enlace', 'url_imagen'];
      }
      array_walk(
        $table_data,
        function (&$row) use ($headings) {
          $row = array_combine($headings, $row);
        }
      );

      /* 
      overkill safeguard: 
      si keys como nombres no existen usar indices 0, 1, 2, 3  
      */

      $idx_titulo = $headings[0] ?? 0;
      $idx_texto = $headings[1] ?? 1;
      $idx_enlace = $headings[2] ?? 2;
      $idx_url_imagen = $headings[3] ?? 3;

      ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
          <?php
          foreach ($table_data as $idx => $datos) {
            /* en variables hace mas facil meterle filtros  */
            $el_titulo = $datos[$idx_titulo];
            $el_texto = $datos[$idx_texto];
            $el_enlace = $datos[$idx_enlace];
            $la_url_imagen = $datos[$idx_url_imagen];

            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($el_enlace); ?>" target="_blank">
              <div class="card text-center">
                <img
                  src="<?php echo esc_url($la_url_imagen); ?>"
                  class="card-img-top"
                  alt="<?php echo esc_attr($el_titulo); ?>">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h3 class="card-title">
                    <?php echo $el_titulo; ?>
                  </h3>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    <?php echo $el_texto; ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          <?php } // foreach data ?>

        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
    } // table tiene datos
  } // table existe
} // class (plugin) exists
```

Comment: (*) El uso del plugin es mencionado por OP en su propia respuesta. `// 1. Crear una tabla en Tablepress y descargarla en csv`