# Es posible conectar la API de Mikrotik en un hosting?

Tags: php

Estoy elaborando un proyecto el cual necesita la conexión a la API de Mikrotik, en el entorno local no tengo ningun problema ya que la API responde las solicitudes; sin embargo cuando subo a producción mi proyecto me arroja un error de tipo:

```
fwrite(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given (0)
```

No he logrado descubrir si el error esta en la API o el hosting esta bloqueando la conexión a esta misma. Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando la libreria [routeros_api](https://github.com/BenMenking/routeros-api/blob/master/routeros_api.class.php)

Comment: ¿Qué dispositivos de red hay entre el Mikrotik y el hosting?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el código `.php` que está generando ese error? ¿Revisaste el registro de errores de tu servidor?

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder, el codigo que esta generando ese error es el de [routeros_api](https://github.com/BenMenking/routeros-api/blob/master/routeros_api.class.php) en la linea `376` para ser exacto y los dispositivos entre el hosting y el Mikrotik no hay, ya que es atravez de la ip pública del mikrotik.

Comment: Sugiero que revises el log de errores en tu servidor remoto (hosting) así sabrás con exactitud qué es lo que está fallando. La librería que estás usando es antigua y puede que tenga problemas de compatibilidad con PHP 7 o superior. O, mejor puedes usar [esta otra librería](https://github.com/EvilFreelancer/routeros-api-php) la cual, según su autor, es compatible con php 7 o superior.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ok muchas gracias por la sugerencia intentare revisar los puntos recalcados. Buena tarde!!

Comment: Por si no encuentras el log de errores en el hosting, te dejo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) en cuyas respuestas se explica el procedimiento para identificar esta herramienta que va a serte de muchísima utilidad para depurar tu código en `.php`.

Comment: yo te sugiero que hagas lo del log que indica A. Cedano, adicional es importante hacer debug y controlar los datos/recursos externos, que pasa sipor algun motivo se perdiece la conectividad con el API... no seria correcto dejar que el sistema  se rompa en ejecucion... en ese caso lo combeniente es capturar esos errores y notificarlo a quien le de seguimiento a la estabilidad del sistema en produccion...

Comment: tambien si no me equivoco un 0 es un false en bolean ... entonces eso quiere decir que en algun momento estas intentando escribir un valor false ... no es correcto ni logico... estoy casi seguro que antes del fwrite hay algun problema y no esta llegando los datos que se esperan para ser escritos.

Comment: No has comentado cómo manejas el puerto público; no es extraño que predeterminadamente esté bloqueado por seguridad, es un blanco fácil mandar indiscriminadamente peticiones al puerto 8728; por eso has de habilitar port-forwarding, aunque para administración remota se recomienda habilitar una VPN. ¿Qué versión de routerOS tienes?.

Comment: @Sal Estoy usando la version 6.49.7 y en efecto para pruebas estoy utilizando el puerto por defecto, deberia cambiarlo? o habilitar una regla que permita la conexion?

Comment: Desde tu entorno local seguramente entras por una interfase LAN en 8728 y eso no cambia; desde un host remoto vas a entrar por WAN en el puerto que designes (preferentemente que no sea de uso común), es recomendable que agregues la regla exclusivamente para la IP del host remoto.