# Se genera el PDF con JSPDF, pero no guarda el pdf ni se envía por correo electrónico

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer, jspdf

Realicé mi código para poder generar un PDF y poderlo enviar por correo electrónico. Va más o menos como [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrGyif6v0x8). El código funciona muy bien en el servidor local, pero al momento de subirlo a mi servidor, me genera el PDF pero no me guarda el PDF en el servidor ni se envía: no sé si es algún problema de mi servidor o mi código.

El archivo se genera bien y se descarga el PDF, pero no se guarda el archivo en el servidor ni se envía por correo.

Código:

```js
function generarPDF(){

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text('texto archivo en pdf');

doc.save('ficha' + nombre + apellido + ".pdf");


    var outputDataURI = doc.output('datauristring');
    var file_data = outputDataURI.split(',')[1];
    var form_data = new FormData(form);
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    form_data.append('nombre', nombre + " " + apellido);
    form_data.append('correo', email);


    try{

        $.ajax({
            url: "../build/php/upload.php",
            dataType: "text",
            Cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(php_script_response){
                alert('Correo enviado');
            },

            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                throw new Error('Hubo un error en la solicitud AJAX');
            }
        });
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.error('Se produjo un error dos: ', error);
        alert(error);
    }
    
}
```

```html
    <section class="contenedor seccion">
        <form class="formulario" id="form" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Información Personal</legend>
                
                <div class="gridForm">
                    <div>
                        <label for="idnombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre" id="idnombre" name="nombre" pattern=".{4,}" title="Minimo 4 characters" required>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div>
                        <label for="idapellido">Apellido</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu apellido paterno y materno" id="idapellido" name="apellido" pattern=".{4,}" title="Minimo 4 characters" required>
                    </div>
                
                    <div>
                        <label for="edad">Edad</label>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Edad en años" id="edad" name="edad" min="4" max="70" onchange="determinarCategoria()" required>
                    </div>
  

                    <div>
                        <label for="idemail">Correo</label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Tu correo" id="idemail" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                

                    <div class="contenido-terminos">
                        <label for="terminos">¿Aceptas las bases de la convocatoria?</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" value="SI" id="terminos" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" class="boton-rojo-transparente-l1">
        </form>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

```php
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

    if(!empty($_POST['file'])){
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['file']);
        file_put_contents('../../doc_pdf/' ."ficha_" . $_POST['nombre'] . ".pdf", $data);
        echo "<span style='color:white;'>se detecto el documento</span>";
    } else{
        echo "<span style='color:white;'>No se ha subido ningún archivo</span>";
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try{
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                                           
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
    $mail->Username   = 'email1mi@email.com';                    
    $mail->Password   = 'micontraseña';                               
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            

    $mail->Port       = 465;                                   

    $mail->setFrom('email2@email.com', 'AYAMM');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['correo'], $_POST['nombre']);     
    // $mail->addCC('email1@email.com');
    $mail->addCC('email2@email.com');

    // $mail->addAttachment('../../doc_pdf/'. $_POST['nombre'] . '.pdf', $_POST['nombre'] . '.pdf');    //Optional name
    $mail->addAttachment('../../doc_pdf/' . "ficha_" . $_POST['nombre'] . ".pdf");

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Ficha de Inscripcion';
    $mail->Body    = 'Te enviamos la ficha de inscripcion al torneo';
    $mail->send();

    echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Comment: Me suena a problema de permisos en el directorio que se va a escribir. Revisa el log de errores de PHP y/o Apache.

Comment: ¿Me podrías indicar como checarlo?
Tengo cero conocimiento en servidores, es un servidor de Hostinger donde intento subirlo

Comment: Para recuperar los archivos en el servidor debes usar [la Super Global `$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php), pero tú estás usando `$_POST`, así no encontrarás nunca el archivo. Dicho eso, el problema no es del todo claro. ¿El correo no se manda del todo, o sí se manda, pero llega sin archivo adjunto? Otra cosa, espero que la contraseña de Gmail que aparece en tu código PHP no sea la correcta. Si lo es, debes cambiarla de inmediato, porque ha quedado públicamente expuesta. El correo electrónico y otra info personal deberías enmascararlas también en la pregunta.

Comment: [Aquí tienes ejemplos de código](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) para saber cómo recuperar archivos pasados por el método POST. Como verás, se usa `$_FILES` y te explica cuáles son las claves que debes usar para recuperar el archivo. En lugar de `fichero_usuario` tú debes usar `file`, porque fue esa la clave que le diste al elemento que transportará el archivo, cuando lo metiste en el FormData: `form_data.append('file', file_data);`

Comment: No se manda el correo electrónico, muchas gracias por el comentario de la contraseña, muchas gracias por el comentario de la contraseña

Comment: Corrige lo dicho sobre `$_FILES` y prueba de nuevo. Si no funciona, revisa los log de error, como sugiere @aeportugal. Y dinos si en pantalla ves este mensaje y qué dice: `echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";`. [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967) te puede servir, para identificar dónde se encuentra el log de errores en tu hosting, y/o activarlo si no lo estuviera. Es una herramienta muy útil para depurar el código, porque te dice cuál es el problema y en qué archivo / línea ocurre. Sin eso, puedes pasar horas y días intentando adivinar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda
use el siguiete códgio para poder ver la super global $_FILES como me surgieren y ya me manda el correo sin el archivo, porque me trae el mensaje de que no se subio el archiv al servidor porque creo que no detecta $_FILES['file´] del ajax

if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
   print_r($_FILES);
   echo '</pre>';
}

Comment: En tu código PHP, convendría que coloques temporalmente un `var_dump($_FILES);` fuera de todo `if`, para verificar qué es lo que está llegando en tu servidor realmente. Puedes colocar el `var_dump` en la primera línea del código, es una depuración temporal.

Comment: No conozco la biblioteca de generación de PDF que estás usando del lado de Javascript. Pero parece sospechoso que esto genere un PDF válido: `var file_data = outputDataURI.split(',')[1];` Eso es lo que tú estás enviando como archivo adjunto, ¿realmente eso genera un `.pdf`? A mí me gustaría ver la salida del `var_dump`.

Comment: Perdón, NO en la primera línea del código, sino debajo de los `use`, los cuales deben ir siempre primero que todo. Y de paso pon también un `var_dump($_POST);`. Así revisamos todo lo que se estaría recibiendo desde el cliente.

Comment: si ese usuario y ese pass son reales, deberias avisar urgentemente que los cambien, y deberiamos editar la pregunta para que esa informacion desaparezca, pero ten en cuenta que ya la expusiste, inclusive aunque borres la pregunta o la edites